# How can I use lodash _.find in my Protractor test?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, protractor, lodash

I want to use the Lodash `find` function to make my Protractor tests more robust.

Instead of

```
    element.all (by.repeater ('topic in topics')).then (function (topics) {

        expect (topics[1].element (by.binding ('topic.name')).getText()).toEqual ('Maths');
        expect (topics[1].element (by.binding ('topic.description')).getText()).toEqual ('2 + 2 = 4');  
    });
```

Something like

```
    element.all (by.repeater ('topic in topics')).then (function (topics) {

        var mathsTopic = _.find (topics, 'topic.name', 'Maths');
        expect (mathsTopic.element (by.binding ('topic.description')).getText()).toEqual ('2 + 2 = 4');    
    });
```

My reasoning is so that, if the order of items in the page changes, the test does not break as it can still find the element with the data it is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it:

```
var mathsTopic = _.find(topics, { name: 'Maths' });
```

Which can be read as: Find me the first topic in topics that has a name property which equals 'Maths'.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using `filter`?

```
var topic = element.all(by.repeater('topic in topics'))
    .filter(function (row) {
      return row.element(by.binding('topic.name')).getText().then(function(name) {
        return name === 'Maths';
      });
    })
   .first()
   .map(function(row) {
     return {
       name: row.element(by.binding('topic.name')).getText()),
       description: row.element(by.binding('topic.description')).getText())
     };
   });

expect(topic).toEqual({
  name: 'Maths',
  description: '2 + 2 = 4'
});
```